# Validating if the fish is caught

Tags: python, list, class, loops

So I have a working grid and random placement of the fish in the grid, what I am unsure is; the user will input a coordinate on the 2x2 grid, and an * will appear on the grid with the fish, but I have no idea how to do that. Also I am unsure on how to validate if the fish and line are in the same cell, meaning the user caught a fish.

Here is all the code so that you can see how everything works together, but the functions that are wrong / incomplete (as far as I know) are

CarpetSea **str** funtion - does not have the * -- I think this has something to do with the if elif else statement in class Cell, but I am not sure

```
    class Coordinate:
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        ''' 

        '''
        self.row = row 
        self.col = col

    def __str__(self):
        '''

        '''
        return "(%d, %d)" %(self.row, self.col)

class Cell:
    '''

    '''

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        '''

        '''
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.coords = Coordinate(row, col)
        self.fish = ""
        self.contains_line = False

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        '''

        if self.fish:
            if self.contains_line:
                result = 'F*'
            else:
                result = 'F'
        else:
            if self.contains_line:
                result = '*'
            else:
                result = ' '

        return result


class CarpetSea:
    '''

    '''

    fish_caught = 0 
    def __init__(self, N):
        '''

        '''

        self.N = N
        self.grid = []
        for i in range(self.N):
            row = []
            for j in range(self.N):
                cell = Cell(i, j)
                row.append(cell)
            self.grid.append(row)


        self.available_fish = ["Salmon", "Marlin", "Tuna", "Halibut"]


    def __str__(self):
        '''
        returns a string representation of a CarpetSea, i.e. display the organized contents of each cell. 
        Rows and columns should be labeled with indices.

        Example (see "Example Run" in the PA8 specs for more):
          0  1  
        --------
        0|M |  |
        --------
        1|  |* |
        --------

        Note: call Cell's __str__() to get a string representation of each Cell in grid
        i.e. "M " for Cell at (0,0) in the example above
        '''        

        str1 = '  | ' + '0' ' | ' +'1' + ' |\n'
        str1 += '-' * 12 + '\n'
        for i, k in enumerate(self.grid):
            str1 += ' {0}| '.format(i)
            for j in k:
                str1 += '{0} | '.format(j)
            str1 += '\n'
            str1 += '-' * 12 + '\n'
        return(str1)
```

drop_fishing_line - not sure how to get the bool condition for the validation that the line is in the user inputted cell

```
    def drop_fishing_line(self, users_coords):
    '''
    accepts the location of the user's fishing line (a Coordinate object). 
    Marks the cell as containing the line.
    '''        

    line_cell = self.grid[users_coords.row][users_coords.col]


    line_cell.contains_line == True

    print(line_cell)
```

check_fish_caught - I don't think anything in this is correct. I have been messing around with it so much it is kinda a jumbled mess

```
    def check_fish_caught(self, fish,):
    '''
    If the cell containing the fishing line also contains a fish, returns the fish. 
    Otherwise, return False.

    '''

    if str(self.grid) == "F*":
        print("The fish was caught!")
        print("\n")

    else:
        print("The fish was not caught!")
        print("\n")
```

And lastly- if everything above gets solved, is there a way to make it so instead of F in the grid it has the first letter of the randomly chosen fish?
Help with any of these funtions would be a life savor, thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide a mvce (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise it will be really difficult to help you.

Comment: @A.Grieco I took out some code, did that make it better?

Comment: No sorry, for my part it's to much effort to at least read and understand your code. You even made it worse, because it's not even running anymore.

Comment: Okay let me try again.. @A.Grieco

Comment: @A.Grieco Okay so I updated it so that my three problems right now have the associated code with the problem below it. I hope this made it easier for you